# Why does Rest Assured say "validation doesn't match" but excepted does match Actual?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am trying to validate this JSON with RestAssured:

```
{
    "valueBounds": [
        {
            "bound": {
                "min": 1.0,
                "max": 4.2
            },
            "date": "2019-01-04T18:40:28.204+0100"
        }
    ],
}
```

with this code:

```
given().when().get(rootPath + "/test/").then().statusCode(200).log().body().
    body("valueBounds.bound.min", hasItems(1.0));
```

Why do I get that they do not match:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path valueBounds.bound.min doesn't match.
Expected: (a collection containing <1.0>)
Actual: [1.0]
```

I have tried to Use Arrays.asList(1.0) but that is not the problem.

Comment: You are using Hamcrest matcher _hasItems()_. Try using _equalTo()_ instead

Comment: It says very specifically: expected "a collection", but got a plain Number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to add a f behind the number:

```
"valueBounds.bound.min", hasItems(1.0f)
```